# Error 502.5 - Process Failure ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, webdeploy

I'm getting this error when deploying my ASP.NET Core web app. I have done the following:

- Enable the Web Server (IIS) role and establish role services.
- Install the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle v2.0.3
- Restart the system or execute `net stop was /y` followed by `net start w3svc`

Here is my csproj file:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" ToolsVersion="15.0">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>MyWebApplication</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageTargetFallback Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp1.0' ">$(PackageTargetFallback);dotnet5.6;portable-net45+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="6.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" Version="14.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Core" Version="2017.2.621" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
   <UserSecretsId>8844d677-223b-4527-a648-387a65933d55</UserSecretsId>
   <ApplicationIcon>wwwroot\favicon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.2.301" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);RELEASE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" arguments=".\MyWebApplication.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I get this error in my Event Viewer:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WWW.MYWEBAPP.COM' with physical
>   root 'C:\inetpub\www.mywebapp.com\' failed to start process with
>   commandline 'dotnet .\mywebapplication.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 :
>   80008083.

Comment: Have you looked at [Asp.net Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5)?

Comment: Yes, see my edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you're missing the Visual C++ 2015 Runtime (available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840)). The hosting package attempts to download and install this during installation, but if there's a network issue or the server isn't able to connect outside (common in Enterprise environments), then it fails, and you'll need to install it manually with the redistributable.

I can't recall whether it was required or not the last time I hit this issue, but you may want to restart your server again, afterwards, just in case.

**EDIT**

If you're still having issues, try running your app from the command line via:

```
dotnet MyApp.dll
```

This will let you see any exceptions being raised at startup.

If you get an error like:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version ...
```

Make sure you have the specific runtime for the version of ASP.NET Core your application is targeting. At the moment, that's either 2.0.3 (for all 2.X apps) or LTS 1.1.5 (for all 1.X apps). You can find the latest runtimes [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows).

Comment: Run the app directly from the command-line: `dotnet run MyApp.dll`. See if there's any exceptions during startup.

Comment: I tried doing that but I got this error: `Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in ... or pass the path to the project using --project.`

Comment: That's an odd error. I'm assuming you ran that in the actual directory where that DLL exists. You did actually publish it right? In other words, it's built not just the straight project files?

Comment: Correct, it builds, publishes successfully but on run-time I get the 502.5 error

Comment: I've posted an edit with the detailed error I'm getting in Event Viewer...

Comment: Doh. My mistake. It should just be `dotnet MyApp.dll`. You only need the `run` for a project.

Comment: Ahhh! Now we're getting somewhere. I saw on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715861/398499 that `Error code: 0x80004005 means a file missing or can't be accessed. Sub-code: 80008083 appears to be a version conflict.`

Comment: Running `dotnet MyWebApp.dll` returns: `It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.1.2' was not found.
  - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
      \
  - Alternatively, install the framework version '1.1.2'.`

Comment: There you go. Install the .NET Core LTS 1.1.5 runtime: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: I installed .NET Core SDK v1.1.2 from here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/1.1.2-download.md and ran again and it works on `localhost:5000`

Comment: Deployed again and getting the same error :( it's working if I run the site manually on the web server but not working on IIS when deployed

Comment: Could it be that the  .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle version does not match the .NET Core SDK version?

Comment: No, the hosting part shouldn't matter. It's just that the 2.0.3 hosting bundle only installs the 2.0.3 runtime, so if you're running 1.1, you need to install that separately. I'd try installing the actual runtime, not the SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows. Get the LTS 1.1.5 version.

Comment: Errr... I meant the .NET Core Runtime, not SDK... ok trying that :P

Comment: You'll likely need to reboot the server or complete stop and start the web services, again, just like after installing the hosting bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I found same problem but my target frame work is **netcoreapp2.0** and I solved it by using Self-contained deployment without third-party dependencies per Microsoft document following. I used use the target frame work **netcoreapp1.0** also and it can solve by using same methodology.

[See here solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAA1FVA0fog&list=PL2kpAKrPYH0RI08vKkj_GWs8CXbUyQYxO)