# 502.5 when deploying ASP.Net Core 2.0 app to Windows Server 2016

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, hosting

I got a brand new `Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Edition` and before deploying my web app with Web Deploy, I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) to set it up and then I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later) to set the environment up. The only difference is that I used `Plesk` to create the web space and then manually changed the `ApplicationPool` CLR version to `No Managed Code` and this has worked on a `Windows Server 2012`. Also `Plesk` created all the required identities and permissions so I'm not using the default `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, but the identity created by `Plesk` and yes, this identity has all the required permissions at the app destination and at `C:\Program Files\dotnet`

I am getting the `502.5 - Process Failure` error in the browser and `0x80070002 : 0` error in the Application Log (the module Log file is empty). I checked all the instructions for that error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis?tabs=aspnetcore2x#common-errors), but nothing changed. Running the app locally on the server using `dotnet MyApp.dll` works fine. I repaired all the `VC++ Redistributable` installations, I restarted IIS and even the whole server, but nothing changed.

Am I missing something or not doing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you use SPA(JSS)?

Comment: Yup, an Angular 5 app

Comment: Is node js installed?

Comment: Also reinstall this https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting and run in cmd iisreset.exe

Comment: Node wasn't (don't know how I forgot about this) but it is now. And I just repaired the Core WSH package. Restarted and still the same

Comment: blah, installation .net core on the server is always blackbox. Check installed version of dotnet on server C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App and check version of your app by packages

Comment: 2.0.3 is on server, don't know where to check in the deployed app, but I am running 2.0.3 locally and have those installed in Visual Studio so I'm guessing they're the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160840/discussion-between-itikhomi-and-gregoryhousemd).

Comment: Are you sure the full path to `dotnet.exe` can be found (e.g. C:\Program Files\dotnet). If you put the full path in the web.config file, does it run OK? See also [ASP.NET Core 1.0 on IIS error 502.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624453/asp-net-core-1-0-on-iis-error-502-5) and [Error 502.5 - Process Failure ASP.NET Core 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555847/error-502-5-process-failure-asp-net-core-1-1#comment82068912_47555847)

Comment: running dotnet myapp.dll works just fine, accessing it from a remote browser is the problem

Comment: The one time I dealt with this type of issue, I had mixed architecture; trying to deploy a 32 bit application on a 64 bit OS. Something to check. Once I get them in sync, everything ran fine.

Comment: I have `Any CPU` at platform target, my server is 64bit... I'll give it a go with x64 only in a moment

Comment: At the moment I can't install Redistributable C++ 2015 because it says that there is a newer version, when there isn't any, except the 2017 one, but aren't they independent?