# ASP.NET Core failed to publish on IIS, gives HTTP error 502.5

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to publish an ASP.NET Core 2.0 Webapplication (MVC) to IIS. But I get the HTTP error 502.5.

[image]

I have tried the following:

- I looked at the event log from Windows, I found the following message; "Application 'MACHINE / WEBROOT / APPHOST / LEVISTEENBERGEN' with physical root C: \ Websites \ levisteenbergen.com \ 'failed to start process with commandline' dotnet. \ Levi Steenbergen.dll ', ErrorCode =' 0x80004005: 1." I still don't how to solve this problem.
- Enabled the 'stdout' in the web.config file, but no log directory was created.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Check in your web.config if the aspNetCore processPath is correct.

Comment: Did you install Windows Server Hosting: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows

Comment: The most common cause of that error by far is either not installing the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle or failing to restart the server afterwards.

Comment: This question may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713848/net-core-app-unable-to-start-in-iis-due-to-errorcode-0x80004005-80008083/49757458#49757458

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42713848/181087) is not an exact duplicate because it is referring to .NET Core 1.0.1 and yours is about .NET Core 2.0, but I believe the solution is the same:

You need to install the [correct .NET Core 2.x SDK version](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md) on the target machine, as it is most likely missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen when you have an exception in your Startup class.

As the other comment mentioned, I've also seen this when the path is incorrect for the aspNetCoreProcess on the web.config

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
You have to enabled the 'stdout' in the web.config file, but also, create a folder with 'logs' otherwise logs will not be created

Answer (score 0):

make sure to check the box for publish to wipe out files on push to server there is remnants of 1.0.1 if that was previously used. Folder needs to cleansed.  This happens on Azure.  Other potential is to force a framework version in the project where the server might not have the updated bits.