# ASP.NET Core ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core

I tried to publish identityserver project to azure app service & also IIS service on VM. But neither works. I checked the error code on app service. Development/production environment works on development machine.

```
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/PROJECT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\' failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\PROJECT.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : e0434352.
```

Error for both ways seems identical

Comment: did you have a look to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42713848/1334561

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Core app unable to start in IIS due to ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008083](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713848/net-core-app-unable-to-start-in-iis-due-to-errorcode-0x80004005-80008083)

Comment: those are different error code. Thanks mates :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

turns out due to persistentdbcontext is not accessible at program.cs in production on IIS/Azure.