# How do I ensure correct DotNet Core gets included in the build?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to deploy a .netcore 2.1.5 api to Windows 2012 Server R2

Currently my published api site gives the following error when I navigate to it

```
HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Common causes of this issue:
The application process failed to start
The application process started but then stopped
The application process started but failed to listen on the configured port

Troubleshooting steps:
Check the system event log for error messages
Enable logging the application process' stdout messages
Attach a debugger to the application process and inspect

For more information visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=808681
```

In the event log I can see

```
Event 1000, IIS AspNetCore Module
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/MYSITE.COM.AU/MYAPINAME' with physical root 'C:\WebSites\MYSITE.COM.AU\MyApps\MYAPINAME\' failed to start process
commandline '.\dotnet .\mydllname.dll', ErrorCode='0x80004005 : 80008083
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713848/net-core-app-unable-to-start-in-iis-due-to-errorcode-0x80004005-80008083)

I see that I can include

```
 <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>False</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
```

In the publish profile If I want to ensure the correct version of DotNetCore gets installed on the host computer.

But how do I set that up if I want to use Azure Devops?

I tried checking Publish Web Projects in the Publish task

but I then get an error

```
No web project was found in the repository. Web projects are identified by 
presence of either a web.config file or wwwroot folder in the directory.
```

Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.

The dependencies include

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5
```

but I don't see a coresponding dll deployed.

I tried installing dotnet-runtime-2.1.5 on the computer, downloaded from
[the installer site](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.5-windows-x64-installer)

[Update]

I noticed the logs folder was missing so I created it manually

[Update]

I added the task suggested by Eriawan
The YAML is

```
    steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.5
```

I get in the log

```
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4839748Z ##[section]Starting: Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4843909Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4843981Z Task         : .NET Core Tool Installer
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4844041Z Description  : Acquires a specific version of .NET Core from internet or the tools cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks.
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4844089Z Version      : 0.1.16
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4844134Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4844192Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853651)
2018-10-29T08:29:05.4844234Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T08:29:05.9812262Z Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 2.1.5.
2018-10-29T08:29:05.9825645Z Checking if a cached copy exists for this version...
2018-10-29T08:29:05.9830151Z Cache does not contains this particular .NET Core. Will be downloaded and installed.
2018-10-29T08:29:05.9833458Z Detected platform (Primary): win-x64
2018-10-29T08:29:05.9833723Z Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 2.1.5.
2018-10-29T08:29:06.5248134Z Could not fetch download information for version 2.1.5. Please check if the version specified is correct. You can refer the link for supported versions => https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases.json. Falling back to creating convention based URL.
2018-10-29T08:29:06.5481883Z [command]C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& 'D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreInstaller_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6\0.1.16\externals\install-dotnet.ps1' -Version 2.1.5 -DryRun"
2018-10-29T08:29:07.6386710Z dotnet-install: Payload URLs:
2018-10-29T08:29:07.6387117Z dotnet-install: Primary - https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip
2018-10-29T08:29:07.6387245Z dotnet-install: Legacy - https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip
2018-10-29T08:29:07.6387445Z dotnet-install: Repeatable invocation: .\install-dotnet.ps1 -Version 2.1.5 -Channel LTS -Architecture x64 -InstallDir <auto>
2018-10-29T08:29:07.6451802Z Downloading: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip
2018-10-29T08:29:08.8792388Z ##[warning]Could not download installation package from this URL: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip Error: {}
2018-10-29T08:29:08.8807163Z Downloading: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip
2018-10-29T08:29:09.5450400Z ##[warning]Could not download installation package from this URL: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip Error: {}
2018-10-29T08:29:09.5453128Z ##[error]Failed to download package for installation
2018-10-29T08:29:09.5551776Z ##[section]Finishing: Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5
```

The designer shows
[image: designer pipeline]

The csproj is

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
           <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\trackApi.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP2_1</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\trackApi.xml</DocumentationFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="logs\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Account\" />
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[Update]

problems in build pipeline

[image: build problem]

[Update]

I created a new pipeline using YAML

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.5


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '**/Api*.csproj'
```

However I still get an error

```
018-10-29T09:36:13.7155347Z ##[section]Starting: Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158688Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158742Z Task         : .NET Core Tool Installer
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158774Z Description  : Acquires a specific version of .NET Core from internet or the tools cache and adds it to the PATH. Use this task to change the version of .NET Core used in subsequent tasks.
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158842Z Version      : 0.1.16
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158878Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158926Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853651)
2018-10-29T09:36:13.7158958Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-29T09:36:14.1220877Z Tool to install: .NET Core sdk version 2.1.5.
2018-10-29T09:36:14.1231419Z Checking if a cached copy exists for this version...
2018-10-29T09:36:14.1238258Z Cache does not contains this particular .NET Core. Will be downloaded and installed.
2018-10-29T09:36:14.1240864Z Detected platform (Primary): win-x64
2018-10-29T09:36:14.1240993Z Getting URL to download .NET Core sdk version: 2.1.5.
2018-10-29T09:36:14.5706519Z Could not fetch download information for version 2.1.5. Please check if the version specified is correct. You can refer the link for supported versions => https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/releases.json. Falling back to creating convention based URL.
2018-10-29T09:36:14.5957734Z [command]C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command "& 'D:\a\_tasks\DotNetCoreInstaller_b0ce7256-7898-45d3-9cb5-176b752bfea6\0.1.16\externals\install-dotnet.ps1' -Version 2.1.5 -DryRun"
2018-10-29T09:36:15.3109409Z dotnet-install: Payload URLs:
2018-10-29T09:36:15.3109790Z dotnet-install: Primary - https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip
2018-10-29T09:36:15.3109942Z dotnet-install: Legacy - https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip
2018-10-29T09:36:15.3110089Z dotnet-install: Repeatable invocation: .\install-dotnet.ps1 -Version 2.1.5 -Channel LTS -Architecture x64 -InstallDir <auto>
2018-10-29T09:36:15.3188675Z Downloading: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip
2018-10-29T09:36:16.5236693Z ##[warning]Could not download installation package from this URL: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-sdk-2.1.5-win-x64.zip Error: {}
2018-10-29T09:36:16.5256084Z Downloading: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip
2018-10-29T09:36:17.2185860Z ##[warning]Could not download installation package from this URL: https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip Error: {}
2018-10-29T09:36:17.2189408Z ##[error]Failed to download package for installation
2018-10-29T09:36:17.2271136Z ##[section]Finishing: Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5
```

The url https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Sdk/2.1.5/dotnet-dev-win-x64.2.1.5.zip   shows an error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>BlobNotFound</Code>
<Message>
The specified blob does not exist. RequestId:7447502f-301e-00a8-516d-6f7cde000000 Time:2018-10-29T09:57:58.4200303Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

[Update]

Eriawan has the answer.
I needed to use a YAML pipeline and get the version here.
[image: the sdk site]

Comment: https://www.benday.com/2018/02/23/force-dotnet-publish-to-publish-dependencies-using-publishwithaspnetcoretargetmanifest/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713848/net-core-app-unable-to-start-in-iis-due-to-errorcode-0x80004005-80008083

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to control the build to use specific version of .NET Core runtime, you must tell the build agent to install the .NET Core SDK to use and also specify the SDK version to install before building your code.

If you use YAML on your Azure DevOps Pipelines build, you could run this task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0 and set the version of to 2.1.403 .

The task must be run before any tasks, preferably the first task to run.

For example:

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  inputs:
    version: '2.1.403'
```

If you're using the build definition designer, add the "**.NET Core Tool Installer**" task and specify the version that you want to use from there.

Please consult .NET Core build sample on MSFT docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?view=vsts&tabs=yaml#build-environment

**UPDATE 1**:

OK, I have seen your build error. Looks like the .NET Core installer task has wrong URL address for .NET Core SDK of 2.1.403.

You can use pure YAML instead. I will file a bug on the .NET Core installer  task repo. In the meantime, please use a full YAML.

I already have one working YAML file, a sample of this is available on my own repo.

For example:

https://github.com/RXCommunica/rx-azuredevops-rest/blob/master/azuredevopsrest-ci-vs2017.yml

**UPDATE 2**:

I have added comments for your YAML. The .NET Core tool version on your YAML is incorrect. Update/change your yaml from the original:

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.5
```

to:

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.403
```

This is important, because version of .NET Core runtime is not equal to the version of the actual SDK tool version.

Please consult this doc for the tool version and the related runtime list of .NET Core 2.1:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.1

Comment: @KirstenGreed How do you create the build definition? Do you use YAML or using the visual task designer? And what is the content of the csproj of your ASP.NET Core project?

Comment: using the visual designer. I will update the question.

Comment: @KirstenGreed please do not edit/update my answer directly.

Comment: @KirstenGreed I have updated my answer. For now, please use full YAML instead of using the designer.

Comment: @KirstenGreed on your YAML file, change the value `2.1.5` to `'2.1.403'` (with the single quote) to sync up with related .NET Core SDK for .NET Core 2.1.5 runtime. Please let me know if it fails.

Comment: Continued at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057748/failed-to-start-process-with-commandline-dotnet-amyapi-dll-errorcode-0x8