# How do I port a pipeline from the visual designer into a YAML pipeline? While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53038709/how-do-i-ensure-correct-dotnet-core-gets-installed-via-azure-devops-for-an-api) I needed to switch to a YAML pipeline.
Thus I started a new pipeline and pasted in the YAML task by task from the visual designer.

I am guessing that I don't need to repeat the word

```
steps:
```

Thus the whole pipeline is now

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.403


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '**/Api*.csproj'

    #Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish

    publishWebProjects: false

    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

But this gives an error

```
azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 35, Col: 5, Idx: 1118) - (Line: 35, Col: 6, Idx: 1119): While parsing a block mapping, did not find expected key.
```

Comment: I note it is trying to build with  version  2.141.0   where as I am referring to 2.1.403 earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in this line `- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1`, the line with spaces. just stick the text to the beginning of the line.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk 2.1.5'
  inputs:
    version: 2.1.403


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore

    projects: '**/Api*.csproj'

    #Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘Parameters.projects’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references the ‘BuildConfiguration’ variable, which you’ve selected to be settable at queue time. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab, and then select the option to make it settable at queue time. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865971

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish

    publishWebProjects: false

    projects: '$(Parameters.projects)'

    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Comment: Otherwise, pasting the Yaml code in task by task without repeating "steps:" seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052083/errorproject-files-matching-the-specified-pattern-were-not-found

Comment: the complete YAM can be found at the Pipeline task.